# Ember.js: what's the difference between the object model and model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model

In the [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/), I found there are two models: `The object model` and `models`, and some tutorials prefer the previous one and some prefer the another,

so what the differences between them? In which situation I should choose which one?

Comment: Trek's answer is right, but to put it simply, *Object Model* refers to how the Ember Framework itself is modeled. *Model* is the data representation layer of the application you are developing/coding (the model for your own app).

Answer (score 0):

[Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_model) is just a generic computing term. In the Ember.js sense it is the extension of JavaScript's prototypal object model that starts in `Ember.Object` and applies to all extensions of the `Ember.Object` constructor.

[Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model) usually refers to data objects, their properties, and  their associations to other data objects. In web programming the term has become overloaded to mean "objects whose data are persisted into a long-term persistence store" (see [Active Record's Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) or [Backbone's models](http://backbonejs.org/#Model), [Django's models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/), etc).

the `DS.Model` provided by `ember-data` is this kind of object: it's related to persistence. The general object model is all other objects (including the data models).